# DateTime.Parse() works on one machine but not the other

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using the `Parse` method to convert a `string` to a `DateTime` object:

```
requestRecord.TerminationDate = DateTime.Parse(reader.ReadString("Termination_Date"));
```

This code works on one machine but throws an exception on the other. I think the issue may perhaps be to do with the local culture. Looking at the taskbars on the two machines the one that throws the exception has the date as `01/12/2014` whereas the other shows `12/01/2014`.

Is there some way that I can rewrite the above code so that it works on both machines regardless of the local `DateTime` culture?

Comment: What is the `reader`? and why are you reading it as string in first place?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, probably because `BinaryReader` doesn't have a `ReadDate()` method?

Comment: @KirkWoll How sure are you that reader is `BinaryReader`? [BinaryReader.ReadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't takes any string parameter.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, that's a good point.

Answer (score 8):

I guess the culture settings differ on both machines. Try to supply the format. That explains why the date format is interpreted differently on both machines:

```
requestRecord.TerminationDate = DateTime.ParseExact
                                ( reader.ReadString("Termination_Date")
                                , "dd/MM/yyyy"
                                , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                                );
```

In this way, you are not depending on the machine and it's settings, but on the format you know.

Depending on what `reader` is, you might want to use `reader.GetDateTime`, which does all this for you already, for example [`SqlDataReader.GetDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This will still fail on a machine using US culture. He is reading a locally formatted date so trying to force the `InvariantCulture` will not help here...

Comment: @toadflakz: OP doesn't tell it is a `DateTime` from a database or so he is reading, just a `string`. The answer both provides the code fix, as the long term better solution, if applicable.

Comment: This is completely wrong. `ParseExact` requires *exact* match, so don't see how this will work in multi format cases. Try to `ParseExact` over MM/dd/yyyy and dd/MM/yyyy...

Comment: @Tigran: Which 'multiple formats'? I didn't read them in the question.

Comment: OP's complains about a fact that on one PC it does not work, and the difference between PCs *he* found is in date format, quoting: ".. one that throws the exception has the date as 01/12/2014 whereas the other shows 12/01/2014..."

Comment: @Tigran: He is "Looking at the taskbars", not the actual data. He self-analyzed the problem, but doesn't know how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, you're right - 2 different local formats, 1 formatted string - your solution is correct.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks for the answer. When I tried it however I got the following exception: The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar

Comment: @PatrickHofman Does this answer require the string to be in a certain format starting off?

Comment: @Sperick: Yes, `dd/MM/yyyy`. What is the format of the text? Is it text in the first place?

Comment: @PatrickHofman My dates are going to be in two different formats though (depending on environment). So surely that will work on one machine but not the other?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes it's text. So in one it's it'll be "31/12/9999" and the other will be "12/31/9999"

Comment: @PatrickHofman  It's from an IDataReader object. I tried your alternative solution using GetDateTime but that threw a casting error

Comment: @Sperick: What is the original data source?

Comment: @PatrickHofman a SQLServer database. The data is being read in the reader object which implements the IReader interface

Comment: @Sperick: And what is the data type on the server?

Comment: @Sperick: Then `GetDateTime` is your best option. Sure the value isn't null?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I used the GetOrdinal to save the int to use with GetDateTime. In the intermediate window I could see values for the Termination_Date but when I tried getDateTime(ordinal) I got a casting exception

Comment: @Sperick: That doesn't exist as far as I know. Can you see in the debugger what isn't value is? Try `GetValue`.

Comment: @Sperick: Got to go. Just ping me and I will try to help.

Comment: @PatrickHofman ok thanks. reader.GetValue(1) returns "12/31/9999"

Comment: @Sperick: As a `string`? That sounds weird. Maybe it is best to create a new question about this specific problem. Don't know why it would convert a `datetime` in the database into a `string` on the client...

Comment: @PatrickHofman ok it looks like the stored procedure used to retrieve the data is converting this datetime to a CHAR(10) object. I guess that's why the cast from datetime was invalid

Comment: @Spe: makes sense. Can you change that?

Comment: @PatrickHofman no, the stored procedures are used in a lot of other places so are not to be altered