# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime on one PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, date, datetime, date-formatting

**Language:** C#, **.Net framework:** 4.5, **method used:** DateTime.ParseExact

So in one of our projects we're using the following function to parse a string into a DateTime:

```
private DateTime FormatDate(string date, string format)
{
    try
    {
        IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, culture);
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
DateTime startDate = FormatDate("01/17/2016", "M/d/yyyy");
```

On our 3 PCs, this code works perfectly when Date format on each PC is dd/MM/yyyy, but on 2 of the PCs, when their date format is dd-MMM-yy it produces a bug when trying to execute ParseExact:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

While it keeps working on the third PC even when using the dd-MMM-yy format.
I compared Date and Time settings on all 3 PCs, settings are all equal, the one difference is that on the 2 PCs we use Visual Studio 2013 while on the third Visual Studio 2015.

**Exception details:**

Message: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

InnerException: No Inner Exception

Stack:       at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
   at AssetTracking.PopUpWindows.AddItem_Warranty.MakeReminder(TrackersDataContext atdc, Items ni, string itemId) in d:\Solutions\Trackers\Trackers\PopUpWindows\AddItem_Warranty.xaml.cs:line 807
   at Trackers.PopUpWindows.AddItem_Warranty.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3() in d:\Solutions\Tackers\Trackers\PopUpWindows\AddItem_Warranty.xaml.cs:line 685

**The question:**
I'm not sure, is the different IDE part of the problem? or what else can produce this bug on some PCs and not on others having the exact same date and time settings?

Comment: The IDE you're using should have no impact on the instructions your code compiles too. I would think it would be something else like culture settings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230972/datetime-parse-works-on-one-machine-but-not-the-other

Comment: Can you compare the outputs of `DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(new CultureInfo("en-US", true)).GetAllDateTimePatterns()` on each machine? These patterns are tried in `DateTime.ParseX()` methods

Comment: Are you sure that the date string is always passed with the separator matching your format?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @Steve yes the separator is exactly as I mentioned in my post, and on all 3 PCs

Comment: @DirkVollmar I added the exception details in my post

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I compared the lists I got from PCs after I run GetAllDateTimePatterns(), all are the same :/ I noticed one thing not sure if it matters, when I expand the culture variable and in it I expand DateTimeFormats, I can find a property named DateTimeOffsetPattern on my PC (where no bug is being produced), while on the other machine this property is not listed, though I found it under the non-public members

Comment: @Saleem: That looks like the exception you created in your FormatDate method, not like the exception coming out of the ParseExact method. I'd recommend you replace the line with `throw new Exception(ex.Message);` with a simple `throw;´ -- makes things so much easier.

Comment: @DirkVollmar ok I changed the stacktrace output after I removed the my catch and added simply "throw;"

Comment: @JeroenVannevel btw I tried to change the culture to be Invariant and the bug didn't occur when I used it, but the output format was not correct, it remained dd-MMM-yy not like what I passed in the parameter which is MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Please provide the input value for the case the exception is thrown. Currently we have NO idea of the string you're trying to parse...

Comment: @ken2k I provided it in my post, it's exactly as stated, 01/17/2016, and same for 07/19/2016

Comment: @Saleem Roger, then see my answer

Answer (score 1):

First thing is, your exception handling is broken:

```
private DateTime FormatDate(string date, string format)
{
    try
    {
        IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
        return DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, culture);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

There is nothing done in the catch block, so it just breaks the stacktrace. Remove it all:

```
private DateTime FormatDate(string date, string format)
{
    IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
    return DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, culture);
}
```

Second point is, the value you provided *actually doesn't match the pattern `dd-MMM-yy` you specified*. So obviously the `DateTime.ParseExact` function throws an appropriate exception. Here's an example of valid input value:

```
var startDate = FormatDate("11-Mar-16", "dd-MMM-yy");
```

Remove the extra `M` if you meant the month as a number.

Comment: but the ParseExact should'nt be able to take any decent date string and format it into any date format passed in the second parameter? without being affected by the format of the machine where it's executed?

Comment: and if so, then why it does not throw an exception on the other 2 PCs having the same date and time formats as the third?!

Comment: @Saleem What does `ParseExact` do is that it tries to return a valid `DateTime` for the _very specific input value and the very specific format_ you specified. If both don't match, it'll fail. Use `Parse` if you don't expect the input value to _exactly_ match the provided pattern.

Comment: ok I see.. but I still don't get it why it threw the exception on just one of the 3 PCs, would be great if you have an explanation for that, out of curiosity and for future references. Thx.

Comment: @Saleem Could you provide some table that recapitulates the exact list of input values / formats that work / don't work on which machines, it's currently a bit hard to extract from the OP.